# MVC Serving Favicons based on Domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httphandler, favicon

now I have a web application that will be published on multiple domains and I want to support different favicon based on domain

what I had done is :

** Added a handler in web.config called “favicon”, for any request for a file called “favicon.ico”

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name="favicon" verb="*" path="favicon.ico" type="namespace.FaviconHandler, MyApplication" />
// other handlers
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

** then added  class that supports the IHttpHandler interface

```
public class FaviconHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext ctx)
        {
            string path = getFavIconPath(ctx.Request.Url.Host.ToLower());
            string contentType = "image/x-icon";
            path = ctx.Server.MapPath(path);

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                ctx.Response.StatusDescription = "File not found";
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                ctx.Response.ContentType = contentType;
                ctx.Response.WriteFile(path);
            }
        }
        private string getFavIconPath(string domain)
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
            {

                if (domain.Contains("abc.com")))
                    return "favicon.ico";
                else
                    return "favicon2.ico";
            }
            return "favicon.ico";
        }
    }
```

The problem is .. it's not working well..
What I miss??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Couldn't you achieve this easier with JavaScript? Just have a favicon for each domain in a domain specific folder, then construct the URL for the favicon on the client based on window.location. Then set that in the head tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way could be to keep all icon files named with domain names like -

```
images
    - abc.com.ico
    - def.com.ico
```

Make a basecontroller and set a ViewBag property in its `OnActionExecuting` (override it) with hostname -

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
    string host = HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
    ViewBag.Host = host;
}
```

And in your master layout set favicon link like -

```
<link rel="icon" href="~/images/@(ViewBag.Host).ico"/>
```